# Include external type definitions in compilation output

Tags: typescript, yarn-workspaces

I am writing a library in TypeScript: `@cjol/core`. It has a JavaScript dependency `dep`, which does not have an `@types` package available. Instead, I have written a custom `dep.d.ts` file, which makes all the typings work nicely as I develop the library. Everything compiles fine **but** my `dep.d.ts` does not appear anywhere in the output.

When I try to include my library in another client project `@cjol/client`, the client project will not compile. I get an error like this one:

```
../core/build/index.d.ts:2:24 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'dep'. '/home/cjol/.../dep/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/dep` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'dep';`

2 > import { Foo } from "dep";
```

I am also using Yarn workspaces (`@cjol/core` and `@cjol/client` are both packages in the same workspace, under `./core` and `./client`), but I don't think that's relevant here. I need `@cjol/client` to output my custom definition file, but I can't figure out how to make it happen!

---

**Edit 1:** Again, I'm not sure the details are relevant, but here's what `index.d.ts` looks like. As mentioned, it's been generated by TypeScript.

```
import { Stuff } from "a-typescript-library";
import { Foo } from "dep";

export * from "./my-app-types";

declare type APIResponse<T> = {
    /* ... */
};
export declare class API {
    /* ... */
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** Here's what `dep.d.ts` looks like:

```
declare module "dep" {
  import Something from "something.js";
  export class DepClass {
     /* loads of stuff */
  }
}
```

---

**Edit 4:** Perhaps another way of thinking about my question. If I have written a custom `.d.ts` file, how can I distribute it? Do I need to create a whole new package containing the type definition?

Comment: please paste your index.d.ts

Comment: I'm not sure how much that will help, but I've added it now.

Comment: sorry can you paste your dep.d.ts

Comment: Have done, but again - I don't think the details of these files are necessary. The point is that it isn't getting included in the compilation output, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I have same problem @cjol did you ever find a solution for this? I don't want to have to publish a separate package for one module declaration know this is an old issue.

Comment: The closest i've found so far is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471450/exposing-external-module-typescript-declarations-to-consuming-modules

which seems to be the same problem and suggests using a ```///<reference>``` comment. However, i'm not seeing it successfully include the referenced declaration in the output.

Comment: Unfortunately not - it was a hobby project that I abandoned for other reasons. Still keen to find an answer if there is one out there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, typescript will not copy your custom `*.d.ts` files into your output. However, there are a couple ways you can get around this.

First, is to manually copy your custom `*.d.ts` files into your output directory after you have finished running `tsc` and ensuring the directory structure matches how it was in the `src` directory.

The other option is to rename the `dep.d.ts` file into a `dep.ts` file and include it in the module that needs the type.

File now called `dep.ts`

```
declare module "dep" {
  import Something from "something.js";
  export class DepClass {
     /* loads of stuff */
  }
}
```

Import `dep.ts` into the module that needs it.

```
import './types/dep';
import { Foo } from 'dep';

// Rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I know whats going on here as I had this before. I bet you did not create your `dep.d.ts` in the `baseUrl` defined location of the project. Any modules declared in the base root will be picked up automatically by TypeScript, anything else needs to be mapped in the `tsconfig.json`. This property is called `path` - path-mapping.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Example `tsconfig.json` if you add the paths property to this config file with the correct mapping information, it should resolve your issue.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "dep": ["src/typings/dep"] // That location is a example but you need to point that at where your dep.d.ts file is
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've given this a go, but I can't see that it's doing anything differently. If I examine the compilation output, I should be able to find `dep.d.ts` somewhere, shouldn't I?