# Exposing external module TypeScript declarations to consuming modules

Tags: typescript, node-modules, typescript-declarations

I have a published TypeScript module (let's call it `shared-stuff`) that is designed to be imported by other TypeScript modules. This `shared-stuff` module has third-party dependencies that have no `@types`-scoped declarations, so inside of that module there are several declaration files:

```
/lib/declarations/
  something.d.ts
  another-thing.d.ts
```

These declaration files work fine within the context of `shared-stuff`. However, once the consuming app starts importing from `shared-stuff`, TypeScript gives me errors like:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'another-thing'.

I can work around this challenge by having the consumer explicitly import the `.d.ts` files from the dependency, but this is not ideal since every consumer would have to do that same thing.

Is there a way to have a consuming module "inherit" the declarations from a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your consumer (consumer of `shared-stuff`) relies on the typings of `another-thing`, you need to export them too.

One way to do that is using `/// <reference>` in your `index.ts` (and remember to include your `/lib/declarations` in your distribution.

Another way is don't rely on the external typings. i.e., instead of doing:

```
import { SomeType } from 'another-thing'
export function foo(): SomeType { ... }
```

Define that type yourself (inside `shared-stuff`, instead of in `another-thing.d.ts`):

```
export type SomeType = { ... }
export function foo(): SomeType { ... }
```

In theory, the types in `another-thing` should follow semantic version as the library itself, but in reality it is much more prone to breaking changes.

One reason is that the library was not written in TypeScript to begin with, so the library author may accidentally break the types without aware of it.

Therefore, while declaring the types yourself sound fragile comparing to reusing type, it really isn't. (and in your case you are defining them yourself anyway).

Just make sure you have a good suite of tests to catch any type breaking changes.

Comment: Adding `/// <reference path="..."/>` comments to the main script worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to have a consuming module "inherit" the declarations from a dependency?

The conventional way is to have it as a `peerDepenency` and mention in your docs that its required for use e.g. for `react`:

```
npm i shared-lib react @types/react
```

AKA you bring your own version of `react` / `@types/react`

Comment: My question is about declarations that are not in installable `@types` modules but those that are declared in `.d.ts` files local to `shared-stuff`.

Comment: Make them available as installable modules 