# How do I override type of a standard library function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a polyfill that extends the behavior of the `JSON.parse()` function by adding an optional third argument to the reviver callback function.

The polyfill should be imported like this for the end users:

```
import 'my-polyfill';
```

The `JSON.parse()` is defined in the `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts` like this:

```
// lib.es5.d.ts

interface JSON {

  // …

  parse(
    text: string,
    reviver?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any
  ): any;

  // …

}
```

How do I override this definition, so when the polyfill is installed/imported my definition is used instead? E.g.:

```
interface ContextType {
  // …
}

interface JSON {

  parse<Type = any>(
    text: string,
    reviver?: (
      key: string,
      value: any,
      context?: ContextType
    ) => any

  ): Type;

}
```

Comment: If you're writing a polyfill, shouldn't it already exist in *lib.esnext.d.ts*?

Comment: @Bergi good idea, but no, it's not.

Comment: You can't, but you can remove that library from compilation and use your own modified version of it instead. I previously answered a question about a similar scenario [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69539181/438273) that should be of help.

Comment: Just to clarify terminology, the term "polyfill" is used when you are implementing a feature that is already, or is strongly suspected to become, part of standard Javascript. Simply modifying a built-in function for your own needs is *not* a polyfill (and is generally discouraged).

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I AM writing a polyfill for TC39 Stage-3 proposal, so I guess it should be a valid reason to override the basic types :)

Comment: @SlavaFominII Good to know, everything is good then :) Maybe you should make a pull request against Typescript, then, instead of a separate package?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie this is a good idea, I will see if this would be viable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create declarations file and name it, for example, as `polyfill.d.ts`. Then, you should use standard way of extending global types as follows:

```js
declare global {
  interface JSON {
    // Here, you should write your own implementation of `parse` function.
    parse(variable: string): void;
  }
}

export {};
```

`export` is required by TypeScript and you can learn more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499895/11894710) answer and its comments.

Don't forget, that when you create a separate library, this file should exist in final build directory. So, when some user installs your package and imports it, file `polyfill.d.ts` would be automatically applied by TypeScript.

I am not sure, that you are able to make TypeScript transfer declarations file (`.d.ts`) with its own functionality. To do this, we should use some hack, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66164525/11894710). We should name file not `polyfill.d.ts`, but `polyfill.ts` and import it in library's `index.ts` file, so it would be imported by TypeScript and transferred to build directory.